# Dealing with leap years and substituting a new date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dates in a dataframe (df) in python under the column name DATE:

```
0       1998-03-31
1       1998-06-30
2       1998-09-30
3       1998-12-31
4       1999-03-31
5       1999-06-30
6       1999-09-30
7       1999-12-31
8       2000-02-29
9       2000-06-30
10      2000-09-30
11      2000-12-31
12      2001-03-31
13      2001-06-30
14      2001-09-30
Name: DATE, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I want to turn all of the leap year dates XXXX-02-29 into XXXX-02-28.  What is the most efficient way to do this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `pd.datetime` and a `lambda` `apply`:

```
import pandas as pd

# Make DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    pd.date_range('1998-02-28', periods=12, freq='6M'), 
    columns=['Date']
)
print 'Original DataFrame:'
print df
print

# Replace feb 29 with feb 28
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(
    lambda x: 
        x if x.month != 2 and x.date != 29 
        else pd.datetime(x.year, x.month, 28)
)

print 'Processed DataFrame:'
print df
print
```

---

```
Original DataFrame:
         Date
0  1998-02-28
1  1998-08-31
2  1999-02-28
3  1999-08-31
4  2000-02-29
5  2000-08-31
6  2001-02-28
7  2001-08-31
8  2002-02-28
9  2002-08-31
10 2003-02-28
11 2003-08-31

Processed DataFrame:
         Date
0  1998-02-28
1  1998-08-31
2  1999-02-28
3  1999-08-31
4  2000-02-28
5  2000-08-31
6  2001-02-28
7  2001-08-31
8  2002-02-28
9  2002-08-31
10 2003-02-28
11 2003-08-31
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the year is a leap year and then check if there is a 02-29 day.

```
if year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0:
    # day/month check
```

Comment: This answer is the best because it addresses the underlying reason for the requested change.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime

def is_leap_and_29Feb(s):
    return (s.dt.year % 4 == 0) & 
           ((s.dt.year % 100 != 0) | (s.dt.year % 400 == 0)) & 
           (s.dt.month == 2) & (s.dt.day == 29)

mask = is_leap_and_29Feb(df.DATE)
print mask  
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8      True
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
13    False
14    False
Name: DATE, dtype: bool
```

```
df['DATE'] = df.DATE.mask(mask,df.DATE.map(lambda x: datetime.datetime(x.year, x.month, 28)))
print df
        DATE
0  1998-03-31
1  1998-06-30
2  1998-09-30
3  1998-12-31
4  1999-03-31
5  1999-06-30
6  1999-09-30
7  1999-12-31
8  2000-02-28
9  2000-06-30
10 2000-09-30
11 2000-12-31
12 2001-03-31
13 2001-06-30
14 2001-09-30
```

Answer (score 0):

Since only leap years have 29-2 :

```
def _292(date): return (date.month==2) & (date.day==29)
df['DATE'][df['DATE'].apply(_292)]-=pd.Timedelta('1D') # yesterday
```